# CFile read data to buffer

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to get all the bytes from a file to read on a BYTE* variable. I'm trying to read a whole xml file data into memory which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataBlock xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Device>3867242</Device>
    <Manufacturer>COMPANY LTD</Manufacturer>
    <Data>15</Data>
    <VendorID>00-291-647</VendorID>
    <TimeStamp>2014-08-13 12:40:11</TimeStamp>
</DataBlock>
```

But ending up with reading something like:

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataBlock xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Device>3867242</Device>
    <Manufacturer>COMPANY LTD</Manufacturer>
    <Data>15</Data>
    <VendorID>00-291-647</VendorID>
    <TimeStamp>2014-08-13 12:40:11</TimeStamp>
</DataBlock>ýýýý««««««««þ"
```

Below is the code to read it..

```
CFile oFile;
if(oFile.Open(filePath, CFile::modeRead) == FALSE)
  return NULL;

long iFileSiz = oFile.GetLength();
BYTE* pData = new BYTE[iFileSiz];

oFile.Read(pData, iFileSiz);
oFile.Close();
```

I'm getting some garbage character at the end of buffer or some files couldn't be read completely.

Output is captured from Visual studio debugger.

Comment: Capture the return value of `oFile.Read()` and compare it to the value returned from `oFile.GetLength()`.  They should be the same -- however, the `Read` call tells you explicitly how much data is has returned.

Comment: What are expecting to be at the end of the buffer if the buffer is larger than the file? Do you have any code to put anything specific there? If not, what's wrong with garbage being there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any problems with your code. However, I would use `CByteArray` instead of raw `BYTE*`. The following example can be used if you need to read data from binary files:

```
CFile oFile;
if(!oFile.Open(filePath, CFile::modeRead))
  return;

CByteArray fileData;
fileData.SetSize(oFile.GetLength()); 
UINT bytesRead = oFile.Read(fileData.GetData(), fileData.GetSize());
oFile.Close();
```

If you work with text files (need to NULL terminate the data read):

```
ULONGLONG dwLength = oFile.GetLength();

if (dwLength == 0)
    return FALSE;

int nSize = (int)dwLength + 1;
CStringA sData;

try
{
    LPSTR pBuffer = sData.GetBuffer(nSize);
    oFile.Read(pBuffer, nSize);
    pBuffer[(int)dwLength] = NULL;
    sData.ReleaseBuffer();
}
catch(CFileException* pFileException)
{
    pFileException->Delete();
    return;
}
catch(CMemoryException* pMemoryException)
{
    pMemoryException->Delete();
    return;
}
catch(...)
{
    return;
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** This approach is good enough for small files. Please note that it is better to read and process huge files chunk by chunk to prevent memory allocation issues.

Comment: Same output. Ended up with some garbages.

Comment: What is the file you're trying to read? (format, size, etc). How do you print the data read? Why do you think its garbage?

Comment: Please see the main post. I have updated the post with exact file.

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer to show you how to work with text files. Basically, you need to NULL terminate the data read.

Comment: Yes your code is working. But I think reading files size in within 512kb won't be a problem. Isn't it?

Comment: If the file size < 1MB you wont have any issues with this approach. Could you please mark my post as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: If I may do some knit picking, CStringA works fine as long as the input is Latin, otherwise it gets messed up. You can leave it as CStringA if you are confident that the file's encoding is Latin not utf-8

Answer (score 1):

Post is old but I wouls like to add an answer to it, so that it will be helpful for other users in future.

```
CFile oFile;
if(oFile.Open(filePath, CFile::modeRead) == FALSE)
  return NULL;

long iFileSiz = oFile.GetLength();  // Getting is the content length
BYTE* pData = new BYTE[iFileSiz];

oFile.Read(pData, iFileSiz);       //  Reading file content

pData[iFileSiz] = '\0';            //  Add last character as NULL

oFile.Close();
```

Now it will display the exact output as in file.

Comment: `pData[iFileSiz] = '\0';` is undefined behavior. It is writing past the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

common error, since you have to declare the array 1 byte longer than the needed to have space for the terminating NULL:

BYTE* pData = new BYTE[iFileSiz **+ 1**];

**pData[ iFileSiz] = 0;**

Comment: This is not correct. To read the entire contents of a file into a byte array, you only need an array the size of the file. Zero termination is only required if you later interpret that data as a C-style string. This is unrelated to reading the file contents.

Comment: In this case, the original question was "why is there garbage" - well and therefore MY answer solves THIS question.

Comment: No, the question is, why the **debugger** displays garbage. The answer to that question is, that it interprets it as a C-style string. The solution to *that* problem is to use format specifiers in the debugger, not to change your code.